# How many oxygen molecules touch you in your lifetime?

Tags: soft-question, atmospheric-science

Following up on a comment by BlueRaja to [this beautiful answer of Ilmari Karonen](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/76758/8563), I would like to phrase this follow up question:

How many air molecules hit your average human's skin during their lifetime? Actually, make that **how many oxygen molecules do you breathe in your lifetime?**

(In case you want some motivation: Ilmari calculates that the chance for a random oxygen molecule in the atmosphere (though I note that local effects could actually play a role for this one) to have existed in that form since the time of *Homo erectus* is about one in 10<sup>14</sup>. However, there's a lot of them molecules, so maybe you *do* brush up with quite a lot of them often.)

Any takers?

Comment: Feel free to shoot this down if you want, though. I realize this is pretty soft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Analysis for [Jesus's molecule usage](http://rsloan.newsvine.com/_news/2009/05/03/2768580-the-odds-that-youll-breathe-a-single-molecule-of-air-that-once-traveled-through-the-lungs-of-jesus):

> Our breathing rate changes a lot, but on average its about 1 breath
>   every five seconds, or 12 breaths a minute, or 720 breaths an hour, or
>   17280 breaths a day or 6,307,200 breaths a year, and if we live for 32
>   years that gives us 201,830,400 breaths in his lifetime. How many
>   atoms? multiply 2.02e8 total breaths x 1.61e23 molecules per breath to
>   get a total of 3.25e31 total molecules. ...That means for Jesus, there were
>   32,500,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 molecules (325 decillion) that came into contact with his lungs during his lifetime.

I didn't see anything wrong with the author's approach, so say 6,307,200 * 1.61e23 molecules/year (based on 6 liters of air/breath not oxygen). Since you want $O_2$ only then scale that down.

At STP (Standard Temperature and Pressure: 1 atmosphere of pressure, 0C), one mole of any gas will occupy 22.4 liters of space. One mole of any substance contains 6.02 x 1023 particles. Air is about 21% oxygen making 1 liter of air to be about 0.21 liters of oxygen.

To find out how many moles that represents=0.21 / 22.4.  Then use Avogadro's number 6.02 x 10^23 atoms/mole.  1 L = 5.64e21 atoms or 2.82e21 molecules/L.

6L/breath => 1.69e22 molecules/breath

6,307,200 breaths a year => 1.07E29 molecules of $O_2$/year.

How long are you going to live * 1.07E29 = $O_2$ passing into your lungs.

The only two caveats to this answer:  some of these molecules won't be unique and 6L represents gas going into the lungs, not what is utilized.

Say you live 80 years, that's ~8.5e30 molecules of $O_2$.

Comment: OK, but how many *unique* molecules of oxygen?

Comment: @Seamus Impossible to determine, in a small room you might inhale the same O2 molecule a dozen times or more before it attaches to hemoglobin or drifts off somewhere else.