# Interaction between charged particles through static electric fields

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I generally find it pretty primitive to accept that static charges communicate with the help 
of static electric fields without any exchange going on between them such as electromagnetic waves. I wanted to know whether there are any theories that put forth more detailed explanation for this kind of interaction using any wave picture. 
I know that it has been postulated that charged particles radiate energy only when they are accelerated and I  do have few confusions regarding the necessity of the involvement of EM waves in static charge interaction but to shorten up the question I would like to ask the following question :
 what is the relation between speed of EM radiation and electrostatic interaction ?

Comment: Well quantum electrodynamics describes the interaction as the exchange of virtual photons. Does that count?

Comment: @JohnRennie Can I ask other queries related to this topic in a separate question ?

Comment: Yes, if you have questions that you don't think have been addressed before then ask a new question. Don't worry too much about your question being closed as a duplicate. It's not always easy to search this site for duplicates - I must admit I hadn't spotted the duplicate question in this case.

Comment: @JohnRennie What do you think were the inconsistencies that led to the failure of this static electric field theory that led to a revolutionary theory ,i.e.,quantum electrodynamics ?

Comment: I don't think there are any glaring inconsistencies in the classical description of a static field. QED was developed as a way of quantising the classical description.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197/2451 and links therein.