# How do photons mediate (or create) a force?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, coulombs-law, interactions, virtual-particles, carrier-particles

Is there a somewhat intuitive explanation as to why the exchange of a photon between two particles causes a force between those particles? Is there a difference in the way massless and massive particles act in this regard?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142159/50583 (Wherein a scetch of the derivation of the Coulomb force is given, but not a duplicate, since you said *somewhat intuitive*)

Comment: look at pages 172 to 173 here https://books.google.gr/books?id=dhOlpFUZWWwC&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=feynman+diagram+and+row+boat&source=bl&ots=f10Lk4UuN0&sig=9k5PdvBhWWOUy4CH8Maw4mR1skA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=h13pVNi7KZbjaoy5gYAM&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=feynman%20diagram%20and%20row%20boat&f=false

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2244/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Basically recoil, since photons can also carry momentum. The reason why this recoil can also lead to attraction instead of plain repulsion is that the exchanged virtual photon has a definite momentum, so it can not have a definite position at the same time (the position wave of a virtual photon is stretched out to infinity). The momentum can be transfered from the emitting particle to the receiving particle (then the force is repulsive), or the other way round - it can also be transfered from the receiving particle to the emitting one (then recoil is negative, so the force is attractive). For more detailed information on this topic also see [Virtual Particles @ Math.ucr.edu](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/virtual_particles.html).

Comment: You might also find [Matt Strassler's article](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/) interested. It doesn't directly address your question but it is useful background.